# How to write custom node exporter for collecting machine metrics with prometheus?

Tags: windows, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am begineer to prometheus , Actually i am having the prometheus package in my windows system. 'Prometheus.exe' is working fine and i am able to see the data in "localhost:9090" in my browser.

I need to scrape the machine metrics such as cpu's total memory, available memory, free memory and cached memory of my windows system and here i stuck totally, having no clue to do this.

Am i need to write my own node exporter to achieve this? If i need to write own node exporter how to start as a begineer? what is the input format need to pass to prometheus?

Somebody kindly help me how to scrape my windows machine cpu memory details using prometheus and suggest if you any links to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely [write your own exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/), but make sure to check the [WMI Exporter](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter) first (Prometheus' [node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) seems to be limited to *NIX OSs).

Beyond that, there are [a bunch of exporters](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/) you may want to check, for more specific needs.